# Can't get python.manage.py syncdb to work

Tags: python, django, django-syncdb, manage.py

I just created my first django app, initialized variables DATABASE_ENGINE and DATABASE_NAME in settings.py, but now when I run python manage.py syncdb, I get the following error Can somebody help? Does this have to do with having two python versions installed?

I'm a django/python noob, please help. thanks!!

```
my-computer:~/Django-1.1.1 mycomp$ python manage.py syncdb
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    my-computer:~/Django-1.1.1 mycomp$ export PATH=/Users/mycomp/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run manage.py from the root folder of your project.  Looks like you are trying from the Django install folder.

Comment: Thanks I just did exactly that.

cd django_bookmarks

then typed

python manage.py syncdb

That took care of it. thanks for your help!

Comment: What a stupid answer. I mean...I didn't just upvote this because I did the exact same thing...<ahem>